# How to use material-ui's Autocomplete component when using a react CDN

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cdn, react-dom

I am able to use the `[TextField, Checkbox, Button . .]` etc components but unable to render the Autocomplete component from the lab material-ui package.

Here's how I'm adding React and material-ui to my page / file.

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<sript src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.58/index.js"></sript>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

React code:

```
 <script type="text/babel">

    //React hooks
    const {useState, useEffect} = React;

    // Material-ui Components
    const {
        Button,
        Checkbox,
        Autocomplete,
        TextField,
    } = MaterialUI;

    const Current_system = [
        { title: "Abdifatah" },
        { title: "Arneau" },
        { title: "Ben" },
    ];

   function CheckboxesTags() {
        return (
            <Autocomplete
            multiple
            options={Current_system}
            disableCloseOnSelect
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
            renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                <Checkbox checked={selected} />
                {option.title}
                </React.Fragment>
            )}
            style={{ width: 500 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                {...params}
                variant="outlined"
                label="System"
                placeholder="Search"
                />
            )}
            />
        );
    }

    function App() {
        return (
            <div >
                <Button>Button from MUI</Button>
                <br/>
                <TextField />
                <CheckboxesTags />
            </div>
        );
    }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
```

Screenshot of the button and textfield components being rendered:

[image]

The Autocomplete components works when I import MUI-lab like the below but not with CDN.

This will work when doing it on codesandbox or using create-react-app::

`import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";`

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-unisearchabledropdowns-forked-0u050?file=/src/CheckboxesTags.js)

[image]

This is the error I get on the console:

```
react.development.js:245 
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `CheckboxesTags`.
    at CheckboxesTags
    at div
    at App
printWarning @ react.development.js:245
error @ react.development.js:221
createElementWithValidation @ react.development.js:2240
CheckboxesTags @ Inline Babel script:22
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:15015
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17841
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19079
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23970
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22806
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22737
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22700
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22323
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21911
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25512
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26051
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22461
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26050
render @ react-dom.development.js:26133
(anonymous) @ Inline Babel script:57
yq @ babel.min.js:13
s @ babel.min.js:13
vq @ babel.min.js:13
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:13
Fq @ babel.min.js:13
Iq @ babel.min.js:13


react.development.js:245 Warning: 

React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `CheckboxesTags`.
    at CheckboxesTags
    at div
    at App
printWarning @ react.development.js:245
error @ react.development.js:221
createElementWithValidation @ react.development.js:2240
CheckboxesTags @ Inline Babel script:22
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:15015
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17841
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19079
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3942
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3991
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4053
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23994
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22806
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22737
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22700
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22323
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21911
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25512
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26051
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22461
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26050
render @ react-dom.development.js:26133
(anonymous) @ Inline Babel script:57
yq @ babel.min.js:13
s @ babel.min.js:13
vq @ babel.min.js:13
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:13
Fq @ babel.min.js:13
Iq @ babel.min.js:13


react-dom.development.js:25088 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `CheckboxesTags`.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:25088)
    at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:25116)
    at reconcileSingleElement (react-dom.development.js:14082)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14142)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:17020)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17920)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19079)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3942)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3991)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4053)
createFiberFromTypeAndProps @ react-dom.development.js:25088
createFiberFromElement @ react-dom.development.js:25116
reconcileSingleElement @ react-dom.development.js:14082
reconcileChildFibers @ react-dom.development.js:14142
reconcileChildren @ react-dom.development.js:17020
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17920
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19079
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3942
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3991
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4053
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23994
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22806
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22737
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22700
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22323
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21911
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25512
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26051
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22461
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26050
render @ react-dom.development.js:26133
(anonymous) @ Inline Babel script:57
yq @ babel.min.js:13
s @ babel.min.js:13
vq @ babel.min.js:13
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:13
Fq @ babel.min.js:13
Iq @ babel.min.js:13

react-dom.development.js:20115 

The above error occurred in the <CheckboxesTags> component:

    at CheckboxesTags
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20115
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:20148
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:12348
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12369
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20766
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23456
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3942
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3991
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4053
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23181
unstable_runWithPriority @ react.development.js:2764
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11306
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:23020
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22359
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21911
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25512
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26051
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22461
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26050
render @ react-dom.development.js:26133
(anonymous) @ Inline Babel script:57
yq @ babel.min.js:13
s @ babel.min.js:13
vq @ babel.min.js:13
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:13
Fq @ babel.min.js:13
Iq @ babel.min.js:13
react-dom.development.js:4002 Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4002)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4053)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23994)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22806)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22737)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22700)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22323)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21911)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25512)
    at react-dom.development.js:26051
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There isn't a UMD distribution for the Material-UI lab (which Autocomplete is part of), so I don't think this is possible.